# How too write multiple item to a CSV row?

Tags: python, csv

I am doing some text pre-processing. I have a CSV file that has a set of reviews, where each review is mentioned in a new row. I have managed to run some data filtering on each of these reviews (stop word removal, removing unwanted characters, lemmatizing each sentence). The filtered reviews are written back to a CSV file, its code is mentioned below:

```
def export(review_list, path_to_csv):
    with open(path_to_csv, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as out_file:
        review_writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for r in review_list:
            review_writer.writerow([r.rating] + r.tokens)
```

However, I am not able to write each filtered review in one column, the words of each sentence occupy multiple columns, is there a way to get all the words of a filtered review in one column?

[image]

Comment: Is that image your actual input?

Comment: yes, it is the actual output

Comment: Have you considered reading your original file into a `pandas` `Series` object, i.e, one column, and then performing your filtering using regular expressions with `pd.Series.str.replace`?

Comment: What I mean is: it is *an image*. How are you reading from an image? How can we test your code with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether `r.rating` is in column A (I'm not familiar with the `csv` module), but you could try something like `'|'.join(r.tokens)`... so

```
def export(review_list, path_to_csv):
    with open(path_to_csv, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as out_file:
        review_writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for r in review_list:
            review_writer.writerow([r.rating] + ['|'.join(r.tokens)])
```

Basically concatenating each token with | as a delimiter.